# Copy all files from certain file type extension in script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, copy, file-format

I am trying to execute the following command in a shell script where `adir="mydir"` and `extType=*.txt`

```
cp "$adir/$extType" "$destination"
```

However I get:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘mydir/*.txt’: No such file or directory
```

but there is such directory and if I execute it by hand in command line it works.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change `"$adir/$extType"` to `"$adir/"$extType` otherwise glob expansion won't take place and it looks for a file exactly with the name of `*.txt` which can not be found and thus it complains about it with:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘mydir/*.txt’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

Ravexina already pointed out well that globbing doesn't work in double or single quotes, and btw that cp syntax is wrong for multiple files / single destination and needs -t flag.

What you could do as alternative is to use bash arrays:

```
extType=( "$adir"/*.txt )
cp -t "$destination"   "${extType[@]}"
```

Alternatively, loop

```
for i in "$adir"/*.txt ; do cp "$i"  "$destination"; done
```

Comment: The `cp` syntax isn't _that_ wrong: `cp a b c d` copies `a`, `b`, and `c` to _an existing directory_ `d`.